# How to add Totals to rows groups generated by a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this CTE. My goal is to display all the rows in the result set and the total of a column which has a column with the same value.

```
WITH CTEVal AS 
(SELECT RNum, Amount, Tag, TAmount, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, TDate, 101) DESC) AS RowNum 
from [dbo].[viewJD])

SELECT TDate, RNum, 
  CASE WHEN Tag = 'DR' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Amount) ELSE '0.00' END AS Debit,
  CASE WHEN Tag = 'CR' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Amount) ELSE '0.00' END AS Credit FROM CTEVal
```

which returns the result set

```
TDate       Rnum    Debit    Credit
12-22-2015   8      100       0.00
12-22-2015   8      300       0.00
12-22-2015   8      0.00      400
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00    
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00    
12-22-2015   9      0.00      500   
12-23-2015   10     600       0.00    
12-23-2015   10     0.00      100     
12-23-2015   10     0.00      500
```

Expected result set

```
TDate       Rnum    Debit    Credit
12-22-2015   8      100       0.00
12-22-2015   8      300       0.00
12-22-2015   8      0.00      400
            TOTAL   400       400
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00    
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00    
12-22-2015   9      0.00      500   
            TOTAL   500       500
12-23-2015   10     600       0.00    
12-23-2015   10     0.00      100     
12-23-2015   10     0.00      500
            TOTAL   600       600
```

Selecting * from viewJD would return

```
TDate       Rnum    Amount    Tag   TAmount
12-22-2015   8      100       DR    400
12-22-2015   8      300       DR    400
12-22-2015   8      400       CR    400
12-22-2015   9      250       DR    500       
12-22-2015   9      250       DR    500       
12-22-2015   9      500       CR    500       
12-23-2015   10     600       DR    600       
12-23-2015   10     100       CR    600       
12-23-2015   10     500       CR    600
```

Sum of DR = sum of CR is = TAmount

Comment: look at using `ROLLUP` maybe: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx . you haven't scripted a sample of your source data, otherwise i would answer with a complete solution.

Comment: @Jc Balantakbo Can you please tell me what is the data type of the column Rnum in table viewJD ..?

Comment: @Siya Rnum would be int

Answer (score 0):

The format you provide in your expected output is not feasible or advisable. The following code stores them as separate columns.

```
SELECT  TDate,
        RNum, 
        CASE WHEN Tag = 'DR' THEN Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS Debit,
        CASE WHEN Tag = 'CR' THEN Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS Credit,
        (select sum(Amount)
            from [dbo].[viewJD] td2
            where td2.RNum = td1.RNum
                and Tag = 'DR') as Debit_Total,
        (select sum(Amount)
            from [dbo].[viewJD] td2
            where td2.RNum = td1.RNum
                and Tag = 'CR') as Credit_Total
    FROM [dbo].[viewJD] td1
```

This will give you output like

```
TDate       Rnum    Debit    Credit  Debit_Total  Credit_Total
12-22-2015   8      100       0.00     400.00        400.00
12-22-2015   8      300       0.00     400.00        400.00
12-22-2015   8      0.00      400      400.00        400.00
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00     500.00        500.00    
12-22-2015   9      250       0.00     500.00        500.00    
12-22-2015   9      0.00      500      500.00        500.00   
12-23-2015   10     600       0.00     600.00        600.00    
12-23-2015   10     0.00      100      600.00        600.00     
12-23-2015   10     0.00      500      600.00        600.00
```

Not the nicest to look at, but the easiest to use in other queries.

Comment: Can you provide a more appropriate format? I don't really need to make use of CTE any solution would do.   Just as long as I arrive at the expected result

Comment: @JcBalantakbo I've updated my answer. I had the CTE table because that's what you had in your question, but the solution will work without it. I don't quite understand why you want to count the rows ordered by date since the grouping field is already given in RNum.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. I know it is not a fine solution. I have tried using Rollup but could not get the exact result format. So I came up with this.
This is indeed a long solution.
But I hope you would get some idea to solve the problem from this.

Here I have first taken the Debit and Credit separated values into a table variable.
Then I applied SUM to the values and took the complete result to a cte.
I applied DENSE_RANK to get the correct ordering such that the 'total' row comes after the detail rows.
Finally selected records from cte with value 'Total' for column RNum for the row showing 'total'.

```
CREATE TABLE viewJD
( 
TDate Date,
Rnum INT,
Amount INT,
Tag VARCHAR(2),
TAmount INT
)

INSERT INTO viewJD 
VALUES
('12-22-2015',   8   ,   100 ,      'DR',    400),
('12-22-2015' ,  8  ,    300  ,     'DR' ,   400),
('12-22-2015',   8  ,    400  ,     'CR' ,   400),
('12-22-2015' ,  9  ,    250  ,     'DR' ,   500 ),      
('12-22-2015' ,  9  ,    250  ,     'DR' ,   500 ),      
('12-22-2015' ,  9  ,    500 ,      'CR' ,   500 ),      
('12-23-2015' ,  10  ,   600 ,      'DR'  ,  600 ),      
('12-23-2015' ,  10 ,    100  ,     'CR' ,   600 ),      
('12-23-2015' ,  10  ,   500  ,     'CR' ,   600  )

DECLARE @ValTable TABLE
(
TDate Date,
Rnum INT,
Debit INT,
Credit INT
)

INSERT INTO @ValTable 
SELECT TDate, RNum,
  CASE WHEN Tag = 'DR' THEN Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS Debit,
  CASE WHEN Tag = 'CR' THEN Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS Credit 
FROM viewJD

;WITH cte 
AS (
    SELECT *,RowOrder=DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER By RNUM)     from @ValTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  NULL,
        RNum ,
        SUM([Debit]) AS Debit,
        SUM([Credit]) AS Credit ,
        RowOrder  =DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER By RNUM)                  
    FROM @ValTable 
    GROUP BY TDate,RNum

)

SELECT TDate,
    Rnum = CASE WHEN TDate IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE     CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Rnum ) END, 
    Debit,
    Credit 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY roworder,Rnum,TDate DESC

DROP TABLE viewJD
```